# Call different constructors based on the typename in c++ template function

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, type-traits

I have a self-defined set named `MySet`, an integer should be passing to the constructor of `MySet` to construct it. I want to write a function to initialize a `std::vector` of `MySet`.
I wish that this function is also capable to initialize a `std::vector` of `std::set <int>`.

something like:

```
template<typename S>
void init(std::vector<S> &v, int n){
    v.reserve(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(std::is_same<S, MySet>::value){
            v.push_back(S(42));
        }
        else{
            v.push_back(S());
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without using function overloading on `init`?

Comment: `if(std::is_same<S, MySet>::value)` No this is not how metaprogramming is done. In your simple case it may work, but when both branches can't be valid at the same time, you'll be here asking why.

Comment: You might be interested in [`constexpr if`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html), which may make it into C++17 and would solve your problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller In fact, I got an error in this case, since there is no set<int>(int)

Comment: @TartanLlama It looks like a "compile time version" of if, is that correct ?

Comment: @dacapo1142 Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a creator function for your types:

```
template <class S>
S create()
{
  return S();
}

template <>
MySet create<MySet>()
{
  return MySet(42);
}


template<typename S>
void init(std::vector<S> &v, int n){
    v.reserve(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        v.push_back(create<S>());
    }
}
```

Comment: @dacapo1142 The SO way of saying "thank you" is to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer which solved your problem (max one accepted answer per question). This marks the question as solved, and gives both you and the answerer some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is copy-constructible you do not need this init() function, just use the two argument version of `std::vector`'s constructor:

```
std::vector<S> v(10, S(42));
```

Comment: I believe this will not solve the OP's of not having to differentiate between `S === MySet` and `S === std::set<int>`.